# Use images for drawing an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, arrows

Is it possible to draw arrows (preferential with TikZ) with two images: One for the line and one for the tip?

I would like to realize something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use it more than once? I mean is it going to be frequent line style for drawing arrows from a to b or you just want to create this shape once?

Comment: I would like to use it more than once. The company is redesigning the template for presentations and I'm trying to build a tex style to have the ability to make these new fancy presentations - still with tex.

Comment: Using the `shapes.geometric` library of tikz, you can have something like : `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill=blue!10,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4mm}]
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} { \node (l\x) at (0.6*\x,0) {};}
\filldraw[fill=blue!10] ([xshift=2mm] l5.south east) -- ([xshift=2mm] l5.north east) -- ++(5mm,-0.5cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}` but is this portable enough or there must be a genuine line style?

Comment: This is related: [Best way to draw a chevron diagram using Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58656/best-way-to-draw-a-chevron-diagram-using-tikz)

Comment: @percusse yes that's a good starting point. But it would be nice to at least be able to define start and end - and the line should know how many rectangles to draw ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a different approach from what @percusse suggested. I used decorations to get the rectangles along the line:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations.shapes, }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=rectangle,shape width=4mm, shape height=10mm},
            paint/.style={decorate, draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50}]]
        \node (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node [isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=120, draw=blue!50!black, fill= blue!50, inner sep=1.1mm] (B) at (3.05,0) {};
        \path [draw, paint=blue, decoration={shape sep=0.5cm}] (A)-- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It can be tweaked to wrap it into a single macro that takes for argument e.g. the length.

[image]

**EDIT**: Here is another version that is rotationally correct:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, decorations.shapes, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    paint/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50},
    linedeco/.style={decoration={%
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step #1 with {\draw (-1mm,-5mm) rectangle (1mm,5mm) [paint=blue];},
        mark=at position 1 with
            {\node [paint=blue, isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=120, inner sep=1.1mm, transform shape] {};
            },
        }}]
        \node (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node (B) at (3,5) {};
        \path [paint=blue, decorate, linedeco=0.05] (A)--(B);
        \node (C) at (0,-2) {};
        \node (D) at (3,-2) {};
        \path [paint=blue, decorate, linedeco=0.1] (C)--(D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It takes a parameter you need to set manually, depending on the angles.

[image]

Comment: Nice one. You can also add a triangle node in the end with the `markings` decoration and then it would be complete :) Bah, vote cap...

Comment: I like this one! Is it possible to improve it to be able to draw from e.g. (0,0) to (5,3)? Currently the triangle isn't drawn correctly.

Comment: Looks great now!

Comment: @percusse: Thanks! `:)` It would be really nice if I could automate the spacing, based on the actual orientation. I'll have to figure that out later...